# Subset Data.frame Multiple Conditions

Tags: r

I'm trying to subset

```
DF <- data.frame(A =c("One","Two","Three","Four","Five"),
                 B=c(1,1,2,2,3),
                 D=c(10,2,3,-5,5))
```

using the code

```
DF[DF$B == 1 & DF$B == 2,]
```

to get

```
      A B  D
1   One 1 10
2   Two 1  2
3 Three 2  3
4  Four 2 -5
```

but R throws an error

```
[1] A B D
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

There are many 'near' examples here (on stackoverflow) but not as simple as what I'm trying to do.

Comment: This is most probably a new question but ... once subsetted in the example given, I want to multiply each number by two (for example) and replace it in the original DF.  How do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't have two values in the same row as `&` is essentially checking whether 'B' have value 1 and value 2 for a particula row, 
Here, we need `%in%`

```
subset(DF, B %in% 1:2)
```

Or use `|`

```
subset(DF, B == 1| B==2)
```